# Why different image sizes for different density buckets if Android/iOS scales them?

Tags: android, ios, image, scaling, image-scaling

I'm working on an Android+iOS app where we need some images. I want the images to have a "touchable" size, say 15 mm on all devices. For devices with bigger screens I want to fit more images, not make the images bigger.

My problem is *how to select a resolution (in pixels) for the images*.

To make the images 15 mm on all devices there are two strategies:

1. Supply images in different resolutions and select the closest matching
2. Scale them so that they fit

A pro with the first strategy is that it's the only way to get pixel-perfect images. But there are cons as well:

In Android there are different "density buckets": ldpi, hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, etc. Different devices belong to different density buckets. But the precise density may still vary greatly. So if I decide on the first strategy and supply the image in correct sizes for xhdpi (320dpi) a device with 350 or 300 dpi may still belong to that density bucket and the resulting image will vary in size.

Because of that I think the second strategy, scale the images so that they fit, is better. But then I wonder why should I supply the images in different resolutions? And what is the "optimal resolution" (given a size requirement in mm) for each density bucket?

I understand that an image to be displayed on a xxxhdpi display could be more detailed than an image on a low resolution display. So I can see that there is meaning in supplying different images for each density bucket. But I can't see why they should have different resolutions if they are to be scaled anyway?

Why can't all density buckets have images of size 1024x1024 for example? And, given that the originals are the same, why do I even have to supply different images for different density buckets?

Comment: You'll have to rescale the image on Android if you want it to be 15mm exact. But this question is really just "why aren't they making my job easier instead of harder so i have to supply more images", right? The answer to the "why can't all density buckets have images of same size" is simply **aspect ratio**.

Comment: excuse me, but what in the world are you talking about? aspect ratio, as in height vs width? can't see that it has anything to do with density buckets. i posted the question because i want to understand the philosophy: i have no problem writing a script that supplies my images in a hundred different resolutions in whatever directories and naming schemas needed. but i don't like doing things without understanding the reasoning behind it, even if it's just historical reasons or whatever.

Comment: Very helpful question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if I decide on the first strategy and supply the image in correct sizes for xhdpi (320dpi) a device with 350 or 300 dpi may still belong to that density bucket and the resulting image will vary in size.

Only if you set your `ImageView` (or whatever widget is using the image) to be sized based on `wrap_content`. If you set the widget size to be based upon other dimensions (e.g., `15mm`), then Android will choose the image based on density, then scale to fix the specified dimensions.

> why should I supply the images in different resolutions?

Quality. Apparent image quality decreases the more you scale the image. This is particularly true for upscaling an image, though you will encounter problems downscaling as well.

Also, particularly on Android 1.x/2.x devices, this sort of scaling was done using application memory (heap space); avoiding this sort of scaling would be beneficial for memory use. AFAIK, on modern devices, this scaling is done on the GPU, which helps somewhat. However, on the whole, you want to use the smallest resolution bitmap as possible as input that will give you a visual result that meets your needs and user expectations. This is why we use lower-resolution bitmaps for lower-density devices — scaling downward is guaranteed to waste RAM, and not all users have high-end devices with lots of RAM.

> And what is the "optimal resolution" (given a size requirement in mm) for each density bucket?

Density is expressed in dots, or pixels, per inch. Convert your mm value to inches, then multiply by a density to get a value in pixels.

> Why can't all density buckets have images of size 1024x1024 for example?

You are absolutely welcome to do that, if somehow that gives you the results that you want, and it does not waste disk space or heap space for the user.

Comment: Thanks! If I understand you correctly then it's mainly to save RAM/CPU-cycles and disk space then. Still, if I could do with one image at 1024x1024 instead of both that and one at say 256x256, I would save disk space (but not RAM/CPU-cycles). I don't agree that supplying a lower resolution image would yield better quality when scaling down to an even smaller image than a larger original, if that's what you're saying in the "quality" paragraph?

Comment: Regarding the "optimal resolution": you say multiply by "a" density, and I guess it's that density I'm unsure of. Since upscaling should always be avoided I guess a density higher than the highest dpi of an existing device in the given density bucket should be used....

Comment: @Jonatan: "I don't agree..." -- it depends on the artwork. Fine-detailed artwork, that might look great unscaled at high density, may become a blur when downscaled to a lower density. "I guess it's that density I'm unsure of" -- one for every resource directory that you support (e.g., `res/drawable-ldpi/` is 120dpi, `res/drawable-mdpi/` is 160dpi, etc.). Usually, we don't ship drawables in *every* density, but enough that we'll get good results and be reasonable on heap consumption. However, "good results" depends entirely on the artwork.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it depends on the original artwork, I mentioned that in the original question (second last paragraph). Regarding the resolution: is there a guarantee that the next highest image is always selected? I want to avoid upscaling images! Say you have one image at 160 dpi for mdpi and one at 240 dpi for hdpi and you run on a device with mdpi class and 170 dpi. Will the 240 dpi in the other density bucket be selected, or will the 160 dpi be used?

Comment: @Jonatan: The exact algorithm is not documented and may vary by Android version.